# How to pass an array to USQL Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I created a table in Azure DataLake named "Catalog".
This table contains "CatalogCode" column as Id.
I want to create stored procedure to get catalogs by passing catalog codes.

I wrote it using SQL.ARRAY like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS Export;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Export.PrepareContent;

CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS Export.PrepareContent(@CatalogCodes string)
AS
BEGIN;

@CatalogCodesOneString = SELECT * FROM (VALUES(@CatalogCodes)) AS t(CodesString);

@CatalogCodesTable =
    SELECT new SQL.ARRAY<string>(CodesString.Split(',')) AS Codes FROM @CatalogCodesOneString;

@CatalogCodesExploded =
    SELECT Code.Trim() AS Code
    FROM @CatalogCodesTable
         CROSS APPLY
             EXPLODE(Codes) AS r(Code);

OUTPUT @CatalogCodesExploded
TO "/outputs/explosion.tsv"
USING Outputters.Tsv();

END;
```

It's only testing solution, I'm going to use it to join with other tables.
It works fine, but I want to know are there any other solutions?
In TSQL I would use temp tables. What should I use in DataLake and USQL?

Btw, I can't wrote

```
new SQL.ARRAY<string>(@CatalogCodes.Split(','))
```

I must pass @CatalogCodes into table. Then I can use SQL.ARRAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass around data using `SQL.ARRAY` as a stored proc parameter in U-SQL.  Just use it with `CROSS APPLY` and `EXPLODE`, no need to split it separately.  Is that what you mean?  Try this simple example:

Setup script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.test
(
    x string,
    y int,

    INDEX idx_test
    CLUSTERED(x ASC) DISTRIBUTED BY ROUND ROBIN
);


INSERT INTO dbo.test ( x, y )
SELECT *
FROM(
    VALUES
        ( "a", 1 ), ( "b", 2 ), ( "c", 3 )
 ) AS t(x,y);
```

**Stored Procedure with SQL.ARRAY parameter**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testProc(@codes SQL.ARRAY<string>)
BEGIN

    @rs =
        SELECT t.x,
               t.y
        FROM dbo.test AS t
             CROSS APPLY
                 EXPLODE( @codes ) AS a(x)
        WHERE t.x == a.x;


    OUTPUT @rs
    TO "/output/output.csv"
    ORDER BY x
    USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);

END;
```

**Stored proc call**

```
dbo.testProc(new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"a", "c"});
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Comment: Hi wBob, thank you for your answer! Your solution is great, I didn't even think about passing SQL.ARRAY as a parameter. There is one problem. When I try to add one more parameter to stored procedure and call it after that I get the error. CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testProc(@codes SQL.ARRAY<string>, @second string) and dbo.testProc(new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"a", "c"}, "test"); [Image with error](http://i.imgur.com/iFYEso2.png) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFK at the moment, have you tried the other way round?

Comment: abarbolin: This is a known issue that we have on our backlog to eventually fix. Current workaround is to add extra parenthesis around the first argument's expression:

the workaround is to put an extra pair of parentheses around the first parameter:

`dbo.testProc((new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"a", "c"}), "test");`

Answer (score -1):

An example for how to to pass an array to a stored procedure has been added at the official U-SQL Language Reference site under the examples at Calling a Procedure (U-SQL).  See the call to getPeople.

The definition of getPeople can be seen at CREATE PROCEDURE (U-SQL).

(Note: Would provide links but the Gods keep deleting my responses when I do.  Just do a search for "Calling a Procedure (U-SQL)".)